# Bash for loop with spaces

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

I would like to do something like this:

```
COMMANDS='"ls /" "df ~" "du -hs ~/Devel/"'
for i in $COMMANDS; do
    echo $i
done
```

Where the result would be:

```
ls /
df ~
du -hs ~/Devel/
```

But I can't find the right syntax for the spaces.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
COMMANDS=("ls /" "df ~" "du -hs ~/Devel/")
for i in "${COMMANDS[@]}"; do 
  echo "$i"
done
```

This uses an array to store the commands. This feature is also available in `ksh`, `zsh`, but not in `sh`.

Arrays behave like the `"$@"` argument array. Applying a `for` loop on `"${ARRAY_NAME[@]}"` (the quotes are important) will give you each item in succession. If you omit the quotes, it'll all get smushed together and split on the separators present in your `IFS` environment variable (`'\t'`, `'\n'` and `' '` by default).

Comment: This is the correct answer to the specific question asked, but as chepner pointed out, it's a correct step down the wrong path.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Some people think about whether or not they could while others think about whether or not they should. I tend to be the first type. :D

Comment: but not for sh :'(

Comment: @kokbira A sh solution: Separate the command with  a character that's not in the commands and then split on that character, e.g., `COMMANDS='ls / df ~ du -hs ~/Devel/'
( IFS=' '; for c in $COMMANDS; do echo "$c"; done )
` (uses the tab character as a separator).

Comment: @PSkocik, updating, I could use arrays on my bash scripts, so I fell in love with it

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend you not do that at all. First, it's much longer and more complicated than simply writing

```
ls /
df ~
du -hs ~/Devel/
```

Second, flat strings are not able to store nested, space-delimited strings. There is no way (and yes, I'm ignoring `eval`) to differentiate between spaces that separate commands and spaces that separate arguments within a command. You can use an array for *simple* commands, but you can't nest arrays, so as soon as the arguments for one of your commands contain spaces, you are back to the original problem.

```
commands=("ls /" "df ~" "du -hs ~/Devel")  # OK, but...
commands=("ls \"foo bar\"" "echo 'hello world'")  # No.
```

If you want your script to be able to run arbitrary commands specified by a user, have it source files from a known directory instead (that is, implement a plug-in system).

```
command_dir=~/myscript_plugins
for f in "$command_dir"; do
    source "$f"
done
```

where `$command_dir` contains one file for each of the commands you want to run.

Or, define a series of functions, and store their names in an string (function names can't contain spaces, so there's no need for arrays):

```
lister () { ls /; }
dfer () { df ~; }
duer () { du -hs ~/Devel; }

commands="lister dfer duer"
for command in $commands; do 
    $command
done
```

or

```
commands=(lister dfer duer)
for command in "${commands[@]}"; do
    $command
done
```

Further reading: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: I know your answer is more correct, but I marked the other one as it is more simple and enough in most cases. Thanks though !

Answer (score 1):

When there's space issues, take a step back with an eval command that'll help separate spaces/single-quotes (outside of quotes, unescaped) from meta-level spaces/single-quotes (in quotes or escaped).

```
eval "spacefulAnswer=($(command that produces quoted items with spaces))"
for i in "${spacefulAnswer[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
```

Example:

```
echo Hello > toto.txt
echo '"Second Line"' >> toto.txt
echo 'Third\ Line' >> toto.txt
```

Note that the second line contents are quoted on purpose. Also the third line isn't quoted but the space is escaped. Now toto.txt contains: `cat toto.txt`

```
Hello
"Second Line"
Third\ line
```

Note that `cat toto.txt` yields the same kind of result as an `ls` that would list the files of a directory that would contain three files with those names.

Now let's load our array with spaceful items:

```
eval "totospc=($(cat toto.txt))"
```

Here note that, thanks to `eval`, quotes and escaped spaces have been taken of for what they would have been if you had entered them in the command-line i.e., by taking quoting and escaping into account.

```
for i in "${totospc[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
```

This yields three lines, not five:

```
Hello
Second Line
Third Line
```